# How to import an existing MySQL-Database in my MySQL-Docker Container?

Tags: mysql, docker, import

I have created a docker container based on the official image of MySQL from Docker Hub. It works fine, but I have some troubles with the database import.

My file with the SQL-Instructions is already stored in the folder /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d of my container, but it doesn't work! I have copied my sql-import.sql to /var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql-dump/_data, but I can only see the name of my database when I call "SHOW DATABASES;" within my container. There is no table available when I call "SHOW TABLES FROM myDB;". What can I do to import the content of my MySQL Database?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD ./init-scripts/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ADD ./config/my.cnf /root/
RUN cd /root/ && \
chmod 0600 my.cnf && \
mv my.cnf .my.cnf

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=regex
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword

EXPOSE 3306
```

[image: MySQL View in the MySQL-Container]

Comment: Important to know: I start my container with this command: docker run -d --name mysql --rm -p 3306:3306 -v mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro -v datastorage:/var/lib/mysql:rw christian/mysql-test:1.0

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods to import. With docker exec if your contener is running:

**Solution 1:**

```
docker exec -i <id_conteneur> /usr/bin/mysql -u <fooUser> -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb"

cat schema.sql | docker exec -i <id_conteneur> /usr/bin/mysql -u <fooUser> --password=<password> <database>
```

**Solution 2:**

In a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u <fooUser> -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb" 
mysql -u <fooUser> mydb < schema.sql
```

And add to your DockerFile with Run command:

```
ADD create_db.sh /tmp/create_db.sh
RUN /tmp/create_db.sh
```